# Добавление записи в две связанные таблицы

Tags: sql

Объясните пожалуйста, как добавить запись в `SQL БД` в две таблицы со связью "один-к-одному"?

Очевидный вариант - добавить `INSERT`'ом в одну таблицу, получить `SELECT`'ом `primary key`, добавить `INSERT`'ом в другую. Но он выглядит, мягко говоря, не очень оптимально - аж три запроса. А если добавятся ещё связанные таблицы?..

Comment: Не уверен, как в других СуБД, но в postgreSQL, например, имеется ключевое слово RETURNING, которое избавит вас от промежуточного SELECT'a.

А INSERT'ов должно быть столько, сколько и таблиц.

Comment: У меня MariaDB, если что.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSERT может вставить данные только в одну таблицу.

Если хотите в коде клиента написать меньше запросов, напишите триггер на основной таблице и/или хп, если требуется передать значения.

Comment: Извините, а что такое "хп"?.. :\

Comment: Хранимая процедура.

Comment: Хранимая Процедура

Comment: И в чем при использовании ХП будет принципиальное отличие?

Просто второй insert с select-ом переместится в серверную часть.

Может лучше все же связывать таблицы не по автогенерируемому ключу, а по обычным, поступающим извне  данным (общим столбцам в обеих таблицах)?

Comment: avp, насколько я понимаю, общий столбец должен быть уникальным - для корректной связи "один-к-одному". Я, к сожалению, могу гарантировать уникальность только для одного поля - но оно слишком большое, чтобы использовать его как ключ.

Comment: @shau-kote, если все на самом деле как Вы говорите, то скорее всего либо логическая модель данных ошибочна (например, какие-то важные данные реального мира в нее не попали), либо тут две таблицы не нужны.

Comment: > И в чем при использовании ХП будет принципиальное отличие?

avp, я же говорю, если нужно передать параметры. Предполагаю, что во вторую таблицу не только значение ключа вставляется, как и в первую, впрочем.

Comment: @msi, насчет параметров - это и ежу понятно.

По сути ХП  просто переносят часть логики обработки данных и непосредственной вычислительной работы в серверную часть. 

Тут можно выиграть на передаче данных (прежде всего уменьшается латентность), но проиграть как в усложнении общего кода (клиент + SQL), так и в скорости реакции сервера в случае разнообразного потока одновременных запросов.

--

Но в данном  случае мы просто не знаем всех нюансов задачи.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста пример ХП реализующей эту задачу

Comment: Чтобы что-то писать конкретно, нужно знать структуру таблиц. А в чём проблема?

Answer (score 5):

Элегантное решение:

```
INSERT INTO foo (auto,text)
    VALUES(NULL,'text');         # generate ID by inserting NULL
INSERT INTO foo2 (id,text)
    VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'text');  # use ID in second table
```

[источник](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html)

Comment: Это только для MySQL!

Answer (score 0):

При создании записи можно получить последний автосгенерированный id. Например, в PHP для таких целей есть функция mysqli_insert_id().

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант для id использовать guid и получить уникальность априори, потеряв правда в скорости... (тут смайлик, скривившийся как от зубной боли).

Но это так, в порядке полноты возможностей...

Answer (score 0):

На PostgreSQL можно:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (field_name) VALUES (value) RETURNING id;
```

При этом вместо id можно вернуть любой столбец. А потом гнать ещё один INSERT.

Или

```
INSERT INTO table1 (field_name) VALUES (value);
INSERT INTO table2 (id) SELECT table1.id from table1 where field_name=value;
```

---

На MariaDB,например, в PHP mysqli есть `$mysqli->insert_id`;

Answer (score 0):

Для PostgreSQL для этого можно использовать одну из функций:

1. currval(regclass)   bigint  Выдаёт значение заданной
   последовательности, которое было возвращено при последнем вызове
   функции nextval
2. lastval()   bigint  Выдаёт значение любой
   последовательности, которое было возвращено при последнем вызове
   функции nextval

[Источник](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/10/functions-sequence)